# How to send json object as parameter between states using ui-sref?

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have to send list of ids between ui-states, which will not be visible in url.

Following is the link for navigate to another state:

```
<button class="button button-primary" ui-sref="home.product-campaigns.update-multiple-product-ads({adList:productCampaignDetailCtrl.adList})"> UPDATE</button>
```

And here is the defined state which will receive list of ids

```
$stateProvider.state('home.product-campaigns.update-multiple-product-ads', {
        url: '/update-multiple-product-ads',
        params: {
            adList: null,
        },
        templateUrl: 'update-multiple-product-ads/update-multiple-product-ads.tpl',
        controller: 'UpdateMultipleProductAdsCtrl'

    });
```

Comment: Did you try to use $rootScope ?

Comment: Hi, Bill Bilal, I tried $rootScope but it didn't work for me. On every page refresh the value of $rootScope.adList has undefined value.